Doesn't a Sealed Fate of Indiscriminate Heavenly Death Demand Immediate Extirpation?
The verses in Genesis and Rashi's commentary articulate a chronology regarding Noah's activities and God's communications at the beginning of the flood.
The Torah states in Genesis 6: 13-14

וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֜ים לְנֹ֗חַ קֵ֤ץ כׇּל־בָּשָׂר֙ בָּ֣א לְפָנַ֔י
כִּֽי־מָלְאָ֥ה הָאָ֛רֶץ חָמָ֖ס מִפְּנֵיהֶ֑ם וְהִנְנִ֥י מַשְׁחִיתָ֖ם
אֶת־הָאָֽרֶץ׃  עֲשֵׂ֤ה לְךָ֙ תֵּבַ֣ת עֲצֵי־גֹ֔פֶר קִנִּ֖ים תַּֽעֲשֶׂ֣ה
אֶת־הַתֵּבָ֑ה וְכָֽפַרְתָּ֥ אֹתָ֛הּ מִבַּ֥יִת וּמִח֖וּץ בַּכֹּֽפֶר׃
God said to Noah, “I have decided to put an end to all flesh, for the
earth is filled with lawlessness because of them: I am about to
destroy them with the earth.  Make yourself an ark of gopher wood;
make it an ark with compartments, and cover it inside and out with
pitch

Now some rashis:

קץ כל בשר. כָּל מָקוֹם שֶׁאַתָּה מוֹצֵא זְנוּת וַעֲ"זָ
אַנְדְּרוֹלוֹמוּסְיָא בָּאָה לְעוֹלָם וְהוֹרֶגֶת טוֹבִים וְרָעִים.  כי
מלאה הארץ חמס. לֹא נֶחְתַּם גְּזַר דִּינָם אֶלָּא עַל הַגֶּזֶל (סנה'
ק"ח):
עשה לך תבת. הַרְבֵּה רֶוַח וְהַצָּלָה לְפָנָיו, וְלָמָּה הִטְרִיחוֹ
בְּבִנְיָן זֶה? כְּדֵי שֶׁיִּרְאוּהוּ אַנְשֵׁי דוֹר הַמַּבּוּל עוֹסֵק
בָּהּ ק"כ שָׁנָה, וְשׁוֹאֲלִין אוֹתוֹ מַה זֹּאת לְךָ, וְהוּא אוֹמֵר
לָהֶם עָתִיד הַקָּבָּ"ה לְהָבִיא מַבּוּל לָעוֹלָם, אוּלַי יָשׁוּבוּ:
קץ כל בשר THE END OF ALL FLESH — Wherever you find lewdness and
idolatry, punishment of an indiscriminate character comes upon the
world killing good and bad alike (Genesis Rabbah 26:5).  כי מלאה הארץ
חמס FOR THE EARTH IS FILLED WITH VIOLENCE — Their fate was sealed only
on account of their sin of robbery (Sanhedrin 108a).
עשה לך תבת MAKE THEE AN ARK — There are numerous ways by which God
could have saved Noah; why, then, did he burden him with this
construction of the Ark? So that the men of the generation of the
Flood might see him employed on it for 120 years and might ask him,
“What do you need this for”? and so that he might answer them, “The
Holy One, blessed be He, is about to bring a flood upon the world” —
perhaps they might repent (Sanhedrin 108b)

And so the chronology is such - God informs Noah that an indiscriminate annihilation will destroy all flesh due to certain sins and that their fate is sealed due to another sin. Noach is to build an ark for 120 years to give humanity a chance to repent. My sense is that the sealing had already occurred when God speaks to Noach. Or that at least it is occurring as He speaks.

Aren't the notions of indiscriminate killing/fate sealed and let's-give-them-a-long-120-years-chance at odds with each other? Doesn't a sealed fate of indiscriminate death imply that existence demands an immediate extirpation?! You mean that God was going to deliberate for decades, but still not discriminate if some or most humans stuck to their evil ways?

Per the above - their fate was sealed at the get-go of Parshat Noach - they were given a 120 year clawback opportunity. Couldn't God have operated differently? How about God tells Noach to build the ark over a long period of time because things are looking very bad. But God does not yet seal their fate, nor tells Noach such, until the end of the 120 years. Then if they do not repent their fate of indiscriminate death would be sealed and immediately carried out. This latter approach arguably works better with the indiscriminate killing that must occur as a result of their sins. Can God not operate in this fashion? Is it possible to say in fact that their fate was not sealed until after 120 years?



The incident of Sodom and Gomorrah shows the opposite- that even when a decree has been "sealed," prayer can still change the final outcome. Most commentators (including Rashi) reproach Noah precisely for failing to pray for the generation of the flood

Not sure what the question is exactly. You have demonstrated that it isn't immediate, so what are you asking?

You may also want to check out the wording of the destruction of Sedom, before and after the visit of the malachim.

See also the story of Chizkiyahu HaMelech, who had a decree of death against him and was able to undo it through prayer and actions: https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1038.htm  and https://dafyomi.co.il/berachos/backgrnd/br-in-010.htm

Per the Maharal , per Rashi, God sealed their fate after having a change of heart and before informing Noach of the decree. נתהפכה מחשבתו של מקום כו'. פירוש כי "וינחם" הוא לשון מחשבה אחרת, ואם כן על כרחך צריך לפרש כי נהפכה מחשבתו ממדת הרחמים למדת הדין. ומה שכתוב אחר זה (פסוק ז) "ויאמר ה' אמחה וגו'" אף על גב שכבר כתיב "וינחם ה' כי עשה את האדם" (קושית הרא"ם), חדא למחשבה וחד לגזירה, כי "ויאמר ה' אמחה את האדם" הוא הגזירה אשר גזר עליהם, "וינחם ה'" לא הוי רק מחשבה, אבל גזירה לא הוי:
I suggest that teshuva is a condition subsequent to the decree. It has the power to undo it.

Great point, @GratefulD! You're absolutely correct. So how does that not answer your question?

Does anyone know where I can find that pshat on מעבירין את רוע הגזירה which states that the decree doesn't go away (only the evil of the decree does )? Thus teshuva might not have the ability to undo a decree (especially one of indiscriminate total extirpation) but it can change the evil set in motion by the decree. Semantics?

שו"ת בית הלוי דרושים דרוש יד
היוצא מכל הנ"ל דע"י תשובה נתהפך המאמר לטובה, וזהו ביאור דברי הפייטן ותשובה ותפלה וצדקה מעבירין את רוע הגזרה דהרוע של הגזרה מעבירין ונשאר אותו הגזרה עצמו לטובה,
